# Hub compatibility for Felt Nine 60 2017

Tags: repair, hub, compatibility, rear-wheel

I have Felt MTB Nine 60 2017 and I want to change my rear hub but don't know how to look for compatibility. It says 6 bolt QR x 135.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the rear hub? We're not sure what the hub is, but it is likely to be a cartridge bearing hub. If the bearings are worn, a bike store can take them out and replace them. Or perhaps just open the seals and change the grease. If you do just want to change the rear hub, then sure, it can be done, but it might be as economical to change the entire rear wheel.

Comment: What's wrong with the hub? Hub replacement means rebuilding the wheel which is a significant cost compared to the price of a new wheel (especially on less expensive bikes).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to change because it is making a noise that was looking like sand is inside but it was opened cleaned, new grease and it is still the same. It looks like the body is damaged. It can be heard if I move the wheel slowly forward but not on backward

Comment: @Filip by 'opened and cleaned' do you mean the axle was removed and the bearings serviced?

Comment: Not sure because it was serviced in workshop. Above is what they told me. Also there is a small play. Should I run until it stops?

Comment: I want to try to open and clean by myself first but also want to be prepared if replacement is needed. If I buy some cheap shimano hub from 30$ - 40$ and wheel rebuild in shop will cost me not more then 50$. But at top of all I want to try to make it by myself then took it to workshop to re-check.

Comment: Consider buying the parts through the shop, that way they might be more inclined to  help with checking the build over as a courtesy. It's a good opportunity for you to learn new skills though

Answer (score 2):

135 means 135mm rear drop-out spacing - the older standardard for MTBs that is still used on less expensive bikes.

QR is quick release, as opposed to a solid bolt on axle or more modern through axle.

6-bolt refers to the disc mounting standard, the other being Shimano's Center-Lock.

The free hub body width needs to be compatible with 8/9/10 speeds cassettes. You'll obviously need a hub with the same spoke count.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The back wheel got 32 spokes.

Comment: Another option is a complete replacement wheel - could work out cheaper than the hub by itself given labour costs and perhaps needing new spokes.